# need to remove array in the array output

Tags: php, arrays

I am parsing from a plist file using php to `Array`, below is the `var_dump` of the array

```
array (size=4)
0 => 
array (size=6)
  'EventId' => string 'Event1-2013-10-22' (length=17)
  'EventName' => string 'Event1' (length=6)
  'EventDate' => string '2013-10-21' (length=10)
  'EventDetails' => string ' ' (length=1)
  'Field1' => string 'Testing' (length=7)
  'Field2' => string '' (length=0)
1 => 
array (size=6)
  'EventId' => string 'Event2-2013-10-24' (length=17)
  'EventName' => string 'Event2' (length=6)
  'EventDate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
  'EventDetails' => string ' EVe2' (length=5)
  'Field1' => string 'Testing22' (length=9)
  'Field2' => string '' (length=0)
```

I need to remove `array (size=4)` so I get only as below, need help please.

```
0 => 
array (size=6)
  'EventId' => string 'Event1-2013-10-22' (length=17)
  'EventName' => string 'Event1' (length=6)
  'EventDate' => string '2013-10-21' (length=10)
  'EventDetails' => string ' ' (length=1)
  'Field1' => string 'Testing' (length=7)
  'Field2' => string '' (length=0)
1 => 
array (size=6)
  'EventId' => string 'Event2-2013-10-24' (length=17)
  'EventName' => string 'Event2' (length=6)
  'EventDate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
  'EventDetails' => string ' EVe2' (length=5)
  'Field1' => string 'Testing22' (length=9)
  'Field2' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: You have an array or arrays, you CAN'T remove the outer array without losing the entire set?

Comment: Hello please specify the output of array using print_r() function so that we can identify the structure of array

Answer (score 1):

You could try using var_dump on the content of your initial array, using a foreach loop :

```
foreach ($initial_array as $second_array){
var_dump($second_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)  function to remove outer array.

Eg:

```
<?php
$outer_array = array(0 => array(
                            'key1' => 'value1',
                            'key2' => 'value2'
 ));

$new_array = reset($outer_array);
print_r($new_array);
?>
```